# Overwrite the existing WorkSheet in Perl

Tags: perl

My question:

I am writing a perl script for report generation on the daily basis in an Excel Sheet(excel sheet file name : Report.).

```
I have 4 worksheets in this excel sheet. They are
1. Aug19
2. Error Code.
3. success count.
4. failure count.
```

I will keep on appending the reports for 'Aug19' and 'Error Code' by Parsing the existing excel file(Report.) by using the perl modules Spreadsheet::ParseExcel and Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser on daily basis.

But how will I overwrite the worksheets 'success count' and 'failure count' on the daily basis after parsing the existing file.

Please Suggest.

Comment: It would be nice to see some code.  But I don't think "overwrite a worksheet" is a function supported by Excel per se.  You probably need to delete the old version and add the new version.

Answer (score 0):

check perldoc

```
AddWorksheet()
    $workbook = $workbook->AddWorksheet($name, %properties);
```

Create a new Worksheet object of type Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Worksheet.

The %properties hash contains the properties of new Worksheet.

Comment: Hi Ted thanks for the reply. i want to overwrite the existing worksheet not adding a new worksheet.