# Overwriting the existing Worksheet of a Excel File in Perl

Tags: linux, perl

With the reference to [the question I had asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026229/overwrite-the-existing-worksheet-in-perl) is:

My Code is as below:

```
        if ( !-e $xls_file ) #Checking whether to create a new Excel file or not
        {
                #if yes create a new excel file and 4 worksheets
                print OUTFILE "Creatin a new sheet.\n";
                $excelFileHandle= Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($xls_file) ;
                &InitFormatting ($excelFileHandle);#For format of each cell.    
                ($handle, $row, $col)    = &AddSheet("$monthYearStr", "$SHEET_TITLE", @ReportColLabels);
                ($handle1, $row1, $col1) = &AddSheet("$STATUS_CODE_SHEET_NAME", "$STATUS_CODE_SHEET_TITLE", @Status_Code_labels);
                ($handle2, $row2, $col2) = &AddSheet("$SUCCESS_COUNT_SHEET_NAME", "$SUCCESS_SHEET_TITLE", @Success_count_labels);
                ($handle3, $row3, $col3) = &AddSheet("$FAILURE_COUNT_SHEET_NAME", "$FAILURE_SHEET_TITLE", @Failure_count_labels);
                $new = 1;
        }

        else  #File exists needs to parsed and append the data.
        {
                print OUTFILE "Opening the existing sheet.\n";
                my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
                my $workbook = $parser->parse($xls_file);
                if ( !defined $workbook )
                {   
                        die $parser->error(), ".\n";
                }   
                my $worksheet = $workbook->worksheet($monthYearStr);
                ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
                ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

                my $worksheet1 = $workbook->worksheet($monthYearStr);
                ( $row_min1, $row_max1 ) = $worksheet1->row_range();
                ( $col_min1, $col_max1 ) = $worksheet1->col_range();

                $new = 0;
        }

        if ( $new = 1 ) 
        {
                $handle->write($row, $col++, "$present_date", $num_field_format);
                ------Contiuned for remainin row and col for $monthYearStr $STATUS_CODE_SHEET_NAME $SUCCESS_COUNT_SHEET_NAME $FAILURE_COUNT_SHEET_NAME-------
        }

        elsif ( $new == 0)
        {
                ###Appending the data####

                $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
           $template = $parser->Parse($xls_file);
            if ( ! defined $template )
            {
                    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
            }

            my $worksheet = $template->worksheet($monthYearStr);
            my $row = $row_max + 1;

            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row_max, $row_max );
            my $format_number = $cell->{FormatNo};

            $worksheet->AddCell($row, $col++, "$present_date", $format_number);
            ---------Continued for remaining row and col only for $monthYearStr $STATUS_CODE_SHEET_NAME -----------------------------

 }
```

Now, how do I over-write the worksheet sheet success_count and failure_count each time when the excel file exists.
Please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: Are you just keeping track of output from your script, putting it in Excel because it is a nice output format?  If so, I would suggest storing your data in another format, such as CSV.  Then, write a brand new Excel file from that whenever you need to update the results.  This would be simpler than trying to bring in the file with ParseExcel.  It would also be safer, as you would not lose your results if the user deleted or modified the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to tell what to do without the AddSheet subroutine, but you should be able to overwrite the cells in a worksheet using something like this, per the POD:

```
foreach $worksheet ($workbook->sheets()) {
   if( $worksheet->get_name() eq $SUCCESS_COUNT_SHEET_NAME ) {
       $worksheet->write('A1', $success_count);
   }
   elsif( $worksheet->get_name() eq $FAILURE_COUNT_SHEET_NAME ) {
       $worksheet->write('A1', $failure_count);
   }
}
```